# Unknow provider AngularJs when adding in ".run"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I m starting AngularJS. When i try to add my modules "Principal" And "Authentication" to the .run(), i get this message in the console log.
If i remove "Principal" and "Authentication" ... i don't get error.

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=$scopeProvider%20%3C-%20$scope%20%3C-%20principal%20%3C-%20authorization : unpr : Unknow Provider

```
var authentication = angular.module('Authentication',[]);

angular.module('simpleApp',['ui.router','ui.bootstrap','Authentication'])
    .factory('Principal',['$q','$scope',
        function($q,$scope){

        }
    ]).factory('Authorization',['$rootScope','$state','Principal',
        function($rootScope, $state, Principal){

        }
    ]).controller('SigninController',['$scope','$state','Principal',
        function($scope,$state,Principal){

        }
    ]).controller('HomeController', ['$scope','$state','Principal',
        function($scope,$state,Principal){

        }
    ]).config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider',
        function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

        }
    ]).run(['$rootScope','$state','$stateParams','Principal','Authorization',
        function($rootScope,$state,$stateParams,Principal){

        }
    ]);
```

My html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html ng-app="simpleApp" id="ng-app">
     <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/annonce/public/inc/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/annonce/public/inc/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-min.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/annonce/public/inc/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/annonce/public/inc/bootstrap/css/styles.css" >

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/annonce/public/inc/js/jquery-1.11.3.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/annonce/public/inc/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/annonce/public/app/js/angular.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/annonce/public/app/js/angular-route.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/annonce/public/app/js/angular-ui-bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/annonce/public/app/simple/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/annonce/public/app/modules/authentication/services/AuthenticationService.js" ></script>

</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Mik3fly : Admin</a>
        </div>
        <div  id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Index</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CGV</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-lower affix" role="navigation">
    <div class="container paddingLeftRight0">
        <div  class="nav sousmenu">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a ui-sref="home">Connexion</a></li>
              <li><a ui-sref="signin">Autre</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>            
    <div class="container" style="margin-top:50px;" ui-view="content" >  

    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only instances and constants can be injected into `run(...)` blocks.  Check the [AngularJS documentation on modules](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module).

> Configuration blocks - get executed during the provider registrations and configuration phase. **Only providers and constants can be injected into configuration blocks.** This is to prevent accidental instantiation of services before they have been fully configured.
>
> Run blocks - get executed after the injector is created and are used to kickstart the application. **Only instances and constants can be injected into run blocks**. This is to prevent further system configuration during application run time.

Try changing it to `config` and see what happens.  If that doesn't work, you might need to inject `$provide` into a `config` block, or inject `$injector$` into a `run` block, and use those to get your dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot inject $scope into your Principal factory. It is injected through a local when a controller is created through $controller.

Remove $scope as a dependency in your factory, or use $rootScope as you do in your other factory.